# How can I put a lock on my app so It can't be removed from recent screens

Tags: android, locking, recent-screens

I want to put a lock icon to my app. How can I do that programmatically as in some social apps like in the following picture? I want to prevent the user from clearing my app from recent screens or task as it's using services in the background and Oppo, Mi and Lenovo kills it. I already tried it but it didn't work for me

```
startLockTask();
```

[image]

Comment: I disagree with closing the question as it is programming related, but saying it's not possible is also a valid answer. [Relevant Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303031/should-questions-be-closed-if-the-answer-is-simply-no-should-they-be-answered)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, that lock is not implemented by Whatsapp or any other social networking site. That lock is set by the user manually.

And what does that Lock do is whenever the user clears RAM, then all the applications that are locked will not be killed if that (app) is either in the foreground or background. So that's nothing to do with the code of that particular app.

Now, quoting this line: *I want user to prevent from clearing my app from recent screens*.

Users can still clear any of the locked apps manually. That means if they swipe any locked app, then that app will be cleared. That lock only prevents the clearing of app when the user taps on clear RAM.

All in all, You can't set that kind of lock programmatically in any of your apps.

Comment: I have never implemented that lock when I installed messenger or Facebook manually in oppo. Then how they come up with this? And how can i do this manually.

Comment: @ShawnAbrahaam... They aren't locked right now, if you have a look closing then you might see that the lock is opened from one side.

Comment: @ShawnAbrahaam... And talking about how to add that lock... Then it varies on every device... On Xaiomi phones, you have to swipe down the thumbnail of the app from recent apps and then select the lock option... As simple as it sounds.. But I dont know how to get that done on Oppo..

Comment: Yes I finally found a way to do it manually. But now I wanted to ask you that I need to do this for my app all the time? Becuse I tried unstalling messenger and then reinstalled that . It comes with that lock . We dont need to do that manually and it also dont asks about draw over apps permission it comes with both by default. Cant I set it for my app as well ? If yes how can I ?

Comment: No it dont comes up with that lock . Thats what I am asking how can I do that?

Comment: I wanted to add it programmatically just like messenger did . Could you please tell me how?

Comment: @ShawnAbrahaam... That cannot be done programmatically.. and that's the answer.